# only make last child items links work in mmenu

Tags: mmenu

I make a menu with the mmenu plugin, but I have lots of submenus.
All of the items in my main-menu and sub-menus has a link to a page I want to remove the links of parent menus and only the last child menu items had link to the page how I can do that in mmenu.
I want to have a menu like this.
only the items that don't have child menu go to the link!
Sorry for my poor english ... :(

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="page.html">go to page</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="nopage.html">don't go to page</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page.html">go to page</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.html">go to page</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="nopage.html">don't go to page</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="page.html">go to page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="page.html">go to page</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the way that how to do it
open the main plugin js file and search for this

```
d.is("span")&&o.addClass(i.fullsubopen))
```

then change it to this

```
d.is("span,a")&&o.addClass(i.fullsubopen))
```